# rails not making the link between dynamically added nested form and parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

I've got a form 'tasks' and I am dynamically adding a child 'steps' form.

The 'steps' is added through a javascript call to render('steps/form').

The form loads fine, but when submitting the tasks form, the added step is not put into the database.

I assume this is because I'm not linking the two forms together, but I'm not entirely sure.

My code is
Tasks/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @task, :html=>{:multipart=>true} do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :task_name %>
  <%= f.text_field :task_name %>
  
<%= link_to "Add Step", @step, :remote=>true, :class=>'addStep %>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

<% content_for(:js) do %>
   $('a.addStep').click(function(){
      $('div#newStep').append("<%= escape_javascript(render('steps/form'))%>");
   });
<% end %>
```

the steps/_form.html.erb is

```
<p class="fields">
   <%= fields_for :steps do |builder| %>
   <%= builder.label :title %>
   <%= builder.text_field :title %>
<% end %>
```

I believe the problem is that i'm not passing 'f' or 'task' into the 'step' form, but I couldn't figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<%= render :partial => 'steps/form',
             :locals => {:form => f} %>
```

Hope this helps.

**Edit- 1**

Do as follows:

```
<%= form_for @task, :html=>{:multipart=>true} do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :task_name %>
  <%= f.text_field :task_name %>
  <div style="display:none;" id="steps_form">
       <%= render :partial => 'steps/form',
               :locals => {:form => f} %>
  </div>
<%= link_to "Add Step", @step, :onClick=>"js_function_to_change_display_property()", :class=>'addStep' %>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

then you can use simple javascript to view the steps form by changing the display property of steps_form.

Comment: Where would that go Harry? I don't have a render partials tag, I only have render('steps/form'). Could you clarify your answer?

Comment: Hi harry, thanks for editing your answer, but your answer doesn't really solve the problem as a task can have many steps added. By dynamically adding the step form, I can add 3 steps to a task all without leaving the page. I know how to hide/show divs. I think you are on the right path with locals, but I haven't been able to get it to work in my code.

Comment: I just realized that I had jQuery.html instead of jQuery.append, so it wasn't adding the form multiple times, but I've edited the question.

Comment: No, the problem isn't solved. The data from the steps/form does not end up in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to update the params in your parent controller to include the attributes of the child. e.g.

## controllers/task_controller.rb

```
Class TasksController < ApplicationController
  ...

  def task_params
    params.require(:task).permit :name, :description ,
      steps_attributes: [:step, :step_description, :due_date]
  end
end
```

## models/task.rb

```
Class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :steps
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :steps
end
```

## models/step.rb

```
Class Step < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :task
end
```